# getAttributes returning [function getValue] when in a nested for

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

My second example is the one returning [function getValue] and I'm trying to fix it but I can't see what the problem is.

I've been messing around with xmlparse in google scripts, the xml I want to parse keeps all relevant data in the attributes of elements.

Here's a sample of that xml format: https://api.eveonline.com/account/characters.xml.aspx?keyID=1409941&vCode=xagxMH966J2EQinVpoFOBB5H1UidCwsjoTwtBKhhvMVZWqq6Jio4mkiBwv026Olc

Here's some code that works (displayed via log [ctrl]+[enter]):

```
function dialogDisplay() {
  var xmlstring = Xml.parse('<rowset name="characters" key="characterID" columns="name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID"><row name="Jonah Younbrog" characterID="90131303" corporationName="House of Praetor" corporationID="523373135"/><row name="Mador Younbrog" characterID="90149709" corporationName="House of Praetor" corporationID="523373135"/><row name="Marc Younbrog" characterID="747451028" corporationName="House of Praetor" corporationID="523373135"/></rowset>');
  var attributes = xmlstring.getElement().getAttributes();
  for (var i in attributes) {
    Logger.log(attributes[i].getValue());
  }
}
```

And here's the code that doesn't work, it also logs the element names (successfully) and uses nested fors to go through the xml:

```
function fetchToLogger() {
  var assetURL = "https://api.eveonline.com/account/characters.xml.aspx?keyID=1409941&vCode=xagxMH966J2EQinVpoFOBB5H1UidCwsjoTwtBKhhvMVZWqq6Jio4mkiBwv026Olc";
  var assetstring = UrlFetchApp.fetch(assetURL).getContentText();
  var xmlstring = Xml.parse(assetstring, false);

  var elements = xmlstring.eveapi.result.getElements();
  for (var a in elements) {

    Logger.log(elements[a].getName().getLocalName());

    var attributes = elements[a].getAttributes();
    for (var x in attributes) {

      Logger.log(attributes[x].getValue);
    }

    var subelements = elements[a].getElements();
    for (var b in subelements) {

      Logger.log(subelements[b].getName().getLocalName());

      var subattributes = subelements[b].getAttributes();
      for (var y in attributes) {

        Logger.log(attributes[y].getValue);
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getValue` is a function. so you should use `.getValue()`
For example:

```
Logger.log(attributes[x].getValue());
```

Comment: @Medicdude you're welcome. Please accept as solution my answer or Tomasz's answer (if you think is better explained) :) byez

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the actual function, change to:

```
Logger.log(attributes[x].getValue());
```

Note that `Logger.log(attributes[x].getValue` is just a reference to a function, and this is what console shows.